# Evaluation of the integral $I=\int_0^{\infty}[1-J_0(kr)]k^{1-\alpha}dk$

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

How to compute
\begin{equation}
I(r) = \int_0^{\infty}[1-J_0(kr)]k^{1-\alpha}dk,\quad 2<\alpha<4
\end{equation}
where $J_0(x)$ is the zeroth order Bessel function of the first kind.

A paper gives the following result
\begin{equation}
I(r)=cr^{\alpha-2}
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
c = \frac{4\Gamma(3-\alpha)}{\alpha-2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(3-\alpha)\right)B(1/2,(\alpha-1)/2)
\end{equation}
with $B(x,y)$ being Beta function.

It seems the above result does not give a defined value for $\alpha=3$.

Can someone show how to evaluate $I(r)$?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you interested in evaluating the integral and already you have got an answer for it?

Comment: Because I want to know the detail of evaluation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first identity just follows from setting $k=\frac{1}{r}u$, so the point is just to compute:
$$ I=\int_{0}^{+\infty}(1-J_0(u))\,u^{1-\alpha}\,du $$
that depends on the Beta function since the Fourier transform of $J_0(u)$ is simply given by $\frac{\mathbb{1}_{(-1,1)}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$:

$$I = \frac{1}{\alpha-2}\int_{0}^{+\infty} J_1(u)\,u^{2-\alpha}\,du =\frac{2}{\pi(\alpha-2)}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t \sin(st)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}s^{2-\alpha}\,ds\,dt$$
and since for any $t>0$:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(st)\,s^{2-\alpha}\,ds = \Gamma(3-\alpha)\cos\frac{\pi\alpha}{2} t^{\alpha-3}$$
by the residue theorem, the Beta function arises from:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{\alpha-2}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}z^{\frac{\alpha-3}{2}}(1-z)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\,dz.$$

For $\alpha\geq 4$, the function $(1-J_0(u))\,u^{1-\alpha}$ has a non-integrable singularity in a right neighbourhood of zero, since over there:
$$ 1-J_0(u) = \frac{u^2}{4}-\frac{u^4}{64}+o(u^5).$$
When $\alpha=3$, notice that the zero of the sine function and the pole of the Gamma function cancel out, giving:
$$ \lim_{\alpha\to 3}\Gamma(3-\alpha)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(3-\alpha)\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: Can you show how $I$ is evaluated in detail? Thanks

Comment: @ecook: I added some details. We have an integration by parts, a Fourier transform, a consequence of the residue theorem and finally an integral that depends on the Beta function.

Comment: That helps. Thank you for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Given the [Jacobi-Anger expansion](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.12),
$$\cos(z\sin \theta)=J_0{(z)}+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty J_{2k}(z)\cos(2k\theta)$$
by taking $\theta=0$ and re-arranging we obtain the identity,
$$\boxed{1-J_0(z)=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty J_{2k}(z).}$$
Making a change of variables $ z=rk$ and applying the identity above,
$$I(\alpha,r)=r^{\alpha-2}\int_0^\infty z^{1-\alpha}(1-J_0(z))\ dz=2r^{\alpha-2}\int_0^\infty z^{1-\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^\infty J_{2k}(z)\ dz$$
by interchanging the integration and summation we face the integral,
$$J=\int_0^{\infty}z^{1-\alpha}J_{2k}(z)\ dz$$
where the Bessel function has the series expansion,
$$J_{2k}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!\Gamma(2k+n+1)}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2k+2n}$$ so we can use the slight extension of Ramanujan's master theorem established [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4744295/1141581) to find,
$$J=\frac{1}{2^{\alpha-1}}\dfrac{\Gamma\left(k-\frac{\alpha}{2}+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}$$
thus the integral in question is,
$$I(\alpha,r)=\underbrace{\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^\infty}\dfrac{\Gamma\left(k-\frac{\alpha}{2}+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}}_{S(\alpha)}\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)^{\alpha-2}.$$
Now note,
$$\dfrac{\Gamma\left(k-\frac{\alpha}{2}+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}=\dfrac{\Gamma\left(k-\frac{\alpha}{2}+1\right)\Gamma\left(\alpha-1\right)}{\Gamma(\alpha-1)\Gamma\left(k+\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}=\dfrac{B\left(k-\frac{\alpha}{2}+1,\alpha-1 \right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha-1\right)}$$
where by applying the integral representation of the Beta function and summing over $k\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$S(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha-1)}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^1 x^{k-\alpha/2}(1-x)^{\alpha-2}\ dx=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha-1)}\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^{\alpha-2}}{x^{\alpha/2}}\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{k}\ dx.$$
geometric series happily converges,
$$S(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha-1)}\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^{\alpha-3}}{x^{1-\alpha/2}}\ dx=\dfrac{B\left(2-\frac{\alpha}{2},\alpha-2\right)}{\Gamma(\alpha-1)}$$
hence,
$$I(\alpha,r)=\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)^{\alpha-2}\dfrac{B\left(2-\frac{\alpha}{2},\alpha-2\right)}{\Gamma(\alpha-1)}.$$
Some simplifications may be possible.