# On the generalization of Ramanujan's master theorem

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, mellin-transform

> Ramanujan's master theorem states that if $f(x)$ has the expansion,
> $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\varphi(k)}{k!}(-x)^k,\quad
> x\in\mathbb{C}$$ then the Mellin transform of $f$ is given by,
> $$\int_0^{+\infty}x^{s-1}f(x)\ dx=\Gamma(s)\phi(-s).$$

This theorem is already very convenient, but I wonder if a slightly more general theorem can be established; namely when $f(x)$ has an expansion of the form,
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k\varphi(k)}{k!}x^{ak+b},\quad a,b\in\mathbb{Z}.$$
For example, this is useful when evaluating,
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin{(x)}-x\cos{(x)}}{x^\alpha}\ dx$$
as $f(x)=\sin(x)-x\cos(x)$ has the expansion,
$$\sin(x)-x\cos(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}-x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\varphi(n)x^{2n+1}$$
where,
$$\phi(n)=\frac{n!}{(2n+1)!}-\frac{n!}{(2n)!}=\frac{-2nn!}{(2n+1)!}$$
and the integral will follow if I can find the Mellin transform of $f(x)$.

Any ideas on how to derive such a theorem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't just $\sin \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right) (\Gamma (s)+\Gamma (s+1))$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. So the Mellin transform doesn't depend on the values of $a,b$?

Comment: May be I misunderstood. This is the Mellin transform of $f(x)=\sin(x)-x\cos(x)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. Oh yes, but here I am looking for the general case, i.e. when $f$ has the expansion,
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k\phi(k)}{k!}x^{ak+b},\quad a,b\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: Letting $g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\phi(k)}{k!}(-x)^k$, note that $f(x)=x^bg(x^a)$. Just perform the substitution $u=x^a$, to get an integral that is a shifted Mellin transform of $g(x)$.

Comment: @C-RAM. That makes sense. Will you write an answer? If not I don't mind answering my own question.

Comment: You may find [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.02618) of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the conditions of Ramanujan's master theorem are met, the Mellin transform of $f$ is given by
$$\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}f(x)dx=\frac1{|a|}\Gamma\left(\frac{s+b}a\right)\phi\left(-\frac{s+b}a\right)$$

---

To see this, note that $f(x)=x^bg(x^a)$ where
$$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\phi(k)}{k!}(-x)^k$$ so we may perform the substitution $u=x^a$, and then apply Ramanujan's master theorem to see that

$$\begin{split}
\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}f(x)dx&=\int_0^\infty x^{b+s-1}g(x^a)dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac1{|a|} u^{(s+b)/a-1}g(u)du\\
&=\frac1{|a|}\Gamma\left(\frac{s+b}a\right)\phi\left(-\frac{s+b}a\right)
\end{split}$$
for values of $s$ where the integral converges.